# I want to link LOV and Select List. (Oracle APEX 21.1)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to change the "Select List" List when the LOV (P2_LOV_ID) is changed.

I tried setting

- Actions - Settings - Set Type: SQL Statement
- SQL Statement:

  ```
  SELECT SHOP_NAME, GROUP_ID FROM T_ENTRY_SHOPS WHERE ID=:P2_LOV_ID;
  ```

With the same Action and SQL, the value displayed in the Text Field shows the expected `SHOP_NAME`. (`GROUP_ID` column is not displayed. Maybe it's because that Text Field has not multi columns)

But "Select List" List does not change. Was it the wrong property on Action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"LOV" stands for "List of values". It is used in a "Select list item". So far so good.

That `SELECT` statement's result depends on another item - `P2_LOV_ID`.

In that case, you'll have to modify Select item's properties:

- navigate to "Cascading list of values" property group
- set "**Parent item(s)**" to `P2_LOV_ID`

It means that - when you change `P2_LOV_ID`'s value, the next LoV will display different values (that depend on the parent item).

Comment: Awesome!
You helped me twice today.
Thank you :D